# Cannot access method of a child class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I made a toy example of a problem I'm facing with my code:

I have an animal which I don't know what will be after a later stage, so I initialize it to a generic animal.

But later on, I want to make it a cat, so I'm assigning `myAnimal` to be a `Cat`

```
#include <iostream>

class Animal {
public:
    int weight;
    virtual void Sound() {
        // To be implemented by child class
    }
};

class Cat : public Animal {
public:
    void Sound() {
        std::cout << "Miau" << std::endl;
    }

    // Only cats purr
    void Purr() {
        std::cout << "Purr" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    // At this point I don't know which animal I'll have, so I initialize it 
    // to a generic Animal
    Animal* myAnimal;
    animal->weight = 10;  


    // At this point of the code, I know what animal I want, so I assign animal 
    // to be a Cat
    double selectedAnimal = 0;      
    if (selectedAnimal == 0) {
        myAnimal = &Cat();
        // myAnimal = new Cat(); // this will just create a new Cat, losing 
        // the already assigned weight. 
        // I want to "upgrade" my generic animal, keeping its properties and adding 
        // new ones specific to cats
    }

    myAnimal->Sound();
    myAnimal->Purr();     // ERROR: Class Animal has no member Purr

    return 0;
}
```

I think I'm not assigning correctly `myAnimal` to be a `Cat`, but it is still an `Animal`. Howver the compiler doesn't complain when I do `myAnimal = &Cat();`.

So I don't understand if the compiler allows me to assign Animal to the class Cat `myAnimal = &Cat();` why it complains when I try to use a method specific of the class Cat.

How should I reassign my generic animal in such a way that is now a full Cat with all its methods?

EDIT:

Answering some comments:

-Animal should not have a Purr method, only cats purr.

-I don't know at compile time what Animal will I have, that's why I assign it to be generic at the beginning.

I can reassign myAnimal to be a new Cat, but then any variables already set to the generic animal will be lost (eg: Animal might have a weight variable already set before knowing it's a Cat)

I'll try the suggested down-casting by @Some programmer dude

Comment: `myAnimal = &Cat();` - What is this supposed to be doing ? Shouldn't that be `myAnimal = new Cat();` ? And second, the error of no `Purr` method for class `Animal` is self explanatory. Look at class `Animal`. Do you *see* a `Purr` method ?

Comment: `Cat myCat; myAnimal = &myCat` would be another option - as long as the scope of cat is long enough

Comment: `myAnimal->Purr();` animals do not purr, only cats do. You have a design problem.

Comment: Compiler doesn't complain about `myAnimal = &Cat();` because it is not ill-formed (and thus does not need to be diagnosed), it's just undefined behavior

Comment: Animal should not have a Purr method since it's a Cat specific thing. Isn't `myAnimal = new Cat()` not going to create a new class? I already have myAnimal being an Animal, with variables set and configurations done. It's just that now I know it will be a cat, so I want to "upgrade" it to have all functionalities and keep the ones already assigned as a generic Animal

Comment: This is not python, `Animal* myAnimal` will only ever have animal methods, no matter what you assign to it. C++ is statically typed language.

Comment: To solve your problem, the term you're looking for is *down-casting*: `static_cast<Cat*>(myAnimal)->Purr();` But *only* do this if you're 100% certain that `myAnimal` is really pointing to a `Cat` object.

Comment: all the passed comments are correct , but there is a workaround

int main() {
    Animal* myAnimal;
    double selectedAnimal = 0;      
    if (selectedAnimal == 0) {
        myAnimal = new Cat();
    }
    myAnimal->Sound();
    static_cast <Cat*> ( myAnimal )->Purr(); 
    return 0;
}

Comment: If you know at compile time that you have an object of type `Cat`, you can create directly a pointer of type `Cat*`. When you need a pointer of type `Animal*`, it usually means that the type of pointed-to object is not known at compile time. And then, how could you call `Purr()` on it? How should a compiler resolve this call if there was an object with no `Purr` member function?

Comment: Just another point: In your code, you never have a `Animal` object. so `myAnimal->weight = 10;` is undefined behaviour! Just declaring a pointer does not create an object.

Comment: Once you create an object of some type, it has this type through its entire lifetime. You cannot "upgrade" its type, or change it in any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, when creating the Cat ensure that you allocate the memory correctly. Currently you are taking the address of a temporary object i.e. `&Cat()` which is not valid C++.

You can do this in two different ways:

```cpp
// On the stack
Cat cat;
myAnimal = &cat;

// OR
myAnimal = new Cat(); // On the heap (remember to free the cat)
```

Then, when you want to use the animal as a cat, you can use a downcast e.g.:

```cpp
auto myCatPtr = dynamic_cast<Cat*>(myAnimal);
if (myCatPtr) {
    // This means the pointer is valid
    myCatPtr->Purr();
}
```

Here is a [working example](https://godbolt.org/z/zYEPaxrcW).

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Matthias Grün shows how to manipulate C++ to do what you want.
However, my advice is to stop making C++ do what you think is right, and do it the way C++ wants to do it.
C++ wants you to never throw the type of an object away. It is a strongly-typed language. It almost always an "anti-pattern" to throw away the type of an object.
One common technique for avoiding this anti-pattern, is to separate "ownership" from "use". You can use a pointer to unknown-type, easily. Owning an object by a pointer to unknown type is *really* hard.

```
int main()
{
   Cat my_cat;
   Animal* any_animal = &my_cat; // non-owning pointer.
   any_animal->Sound();
   my_cat.Purr();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All that `myAnimal = &Cat();` does is create a temporary of type `Cat` and assign the address of it to `myAnimal`, leaving you with a dangling pointer.  `myAnimal` will point to an invalid address afterwards.

Also, even if it had been correctly assigned, for example by writing

```
myAnimal = new Cat{};
```

it would still require a cast so the compiler knows that it's dealing with a `Cat`, for example like so:

```
auto pCatInstance = dynamic_cast<Cat*>(myAnimal);
if (pCatInstance != nullptr)
   pCatInstance->Purr();
```

Comment: Note that the problem is even with taking the address of a temporary. This is illegal in C++: _The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be an lvalue of some type `T`._